# Error: ConstantsService is not abstract and does not override abstract method getAppScopeKey() in ConstantsInterface

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I'm trying to compile a react native app on Android and I get:

> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> /Users/dorianmariefr/src/socializus/react-native/node_modules/expo-constants/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/constants/ConstantsService.java:29: error: ConstantsService is not abstract and does not override abstract method getAppScopeKey() in ConstantsInterface
> public class ConstantsService implements InternalModule, ConstantsInterface {
> ^
> Note: /Users/dorianmariefr/src/socializus/react-native/node_modules/expo-constants/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/constants/ConstantsService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

I'm on `expo-constants@~11.0.2` and `react native 0.66.3`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove the unimodules package and move to the expo one: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/